# Unable to run Contacts plugin on Phonegap / Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.4

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Trying to listout Contacts from a android phone using Phonegap / Cordova  3.5.0-0.2.4, installed the "Contacts" plugin to the application folder.

After running below sequence of steps,we just get a default cordova index page displayed on 
the device with the message **"Connecting to Device"**

Its not displaying the contacts which are stored on the mobile.

Kindly help us out.Thanks in advance.

```
Step1
$ cordova create conto com.example.conto

Step2
$ cordova platform add android

Step3
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts

Step4
$ cordova plugin list (enter)
org.apache.cordova.contacts 0.2.11 "Contacts"

Step5
Added the following in "app/www/js/index.js"

function read_contacts(){
   var options = new ContactFindOptions();
   options.filter="";
   options.filter="";
   options.multiple=true;
   var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
   navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// display the address information for all contacts
function onSuccess(contacts) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
   var li = '';
   $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
        if(value.name){
            $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
               if(key == 'formatted'){
                   name = value;
               }                      
            });
        }
        if(value.phoneNumbers){
            $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                phone = value.value;
            });
        }                    
        li += '<li style="text-decoration:none;">'+name+' '+phone+'</li>';
   }); 

   $("#contact").html(li);   
}

function onError(contactError) {
   alert('onError!');
}

Step6:
Added the following in "app/www/index.html"



            <ol id="contact"></ol>


Step7
Added the following in app/res/xml/config.xml
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>



 Step8
   Added the following in app/AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


    Step9
    $ cordova run android
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Are there any errors when you do `adb logcat`?

Comment: Where are you calling the read_contacts function? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Did you forget to paste sth?

Comment: How do we debug Cordova Project? Eclispe-console-Logcat output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AOwPCHR3T8a1Bk7i9AHCmMi90Jcj5x-YaD6GKocmkHU/pub

Comment: Also we changed the function name from read_contacts to "onDeviceReady()", still the problem persists

Comment: Ok, I found `file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 24 : Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` in your log file. Because everything should be done in javascript, and the `app` does not exist/does have a syntax error, I think it won't work this way. Where _exactly_ did you add the JS from Step 5?

Comment: Oh, ok. Because app is an object, you can't define functions with `function test(){//test}` but need to use `var app={test:function(){},onDeviceReady:function(){}};`

Comment: step 5, the js code is saved under app/www/js/index.js file. For your reference you can download the complete source code for better understanding, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxed_8T6OPe4YUMyOGM1TTF4dGc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

On Adroid I tested successfully with onSuccess and fields exchanged, like this:

```
navigator.contacts.find(onSuccess, onError, fields, options);
```

Which contradicts the manual but it works.

In the "Developer App" it works as explained in the manual...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the structure of a given application if you are modifying it.
In this case, the 'empty' cordova Project has an `app`-Object in the index.js, which handles the events and hides the (also given) Splash-Screen.

You simply removed all the code in index.js but left the corresponding elements in index.html.

This is how your index.js should work (based on the default cordova project & your code, untested)

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        app.openContacts();
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    openContacts:function(){
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";
        options.filter="";
        options.multiple=true;
        var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, app.onSuccess, app.onError, options);
    },
    onSuccess:function(contacts) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
        var li = '';
        $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
            if(value.name){
                $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
                   if(key == 'formatted'){
                       name = value;
                   }                      
                });
            }
            if(value.phoneNumbers){
                $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                    phone = value.value;
                });
            }                    
            li += '<li style="text-decoration:none;">'+name+' '+phone+'</li>';
        }); 
        $("#contact").html(li);   
    },
    onError:function(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }
};
```

Comment: Its still the same after replacing www/js/index.js with the above code, my app/www/index.html and app/www/js/index.js is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nTUkq0FXhjrNk4MsxG7o1NHIRgH71rkgzSyVUNy2jww/pub  . Im new to this environment, kindly provide me with the correct index.html and js/index.js and point to any other errors if any.

Comment: Please check the error log (adb logcat) again. Those lines containing cordova could be interesting. Is the splash-screen still shown?

Comment: Some progress, logcat output(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZHlNbxt-uZ-tIPcv91sm_o4p-2PLL_o_0y-BoVGEGpg/pub) displays the contacts from the phone but actual output on the mobile screen is splash screen still remains intact, the screen does not change (it does not display the contacts which  I can see in the logcat output)

Comment: Ok. a) you should include jQuery if you want to use it. b) you could simply remove the default `<p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p><p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>`. The 'default behaviour' (as used above) only hides the 'listening'-Screen but shows the 'ready'-Screen. I'll edit the answer to match this.

Comment: Ok, can't find a reason for this. Since it's showing html which is definitely commented, try cleaning everything (from eclipse), removing the app from the device and start over again. If it doesn't work, try remote web inspector for chrome or weinre (there are tons of tutorials), and try to edit something in the running app.